# How to compare latitude & longitude values in SQLite query?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, database-design

I am trying to compare Latitude and Longitude values in SQLite using greater & less than symbols as i used to do in MySQL. All the values are defined as `varchar` in Android SQLite. Below is my query:-

```
    double latt = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    double lonn = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select jn,zone from tbl_zones where " 
            + latt + " >= CAST(sw_lat as DOUBLE) & " 
            + latt + " <= CAST(ne_lat as DOUBLE) & " 
            + lonn + " >= CAST(sw_lon as DOUBLE) & " 
            + lonn + " <= CAST(ne_lon as DOUBLE)", null);

String myjn = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("jn"));
```

Here SQLite is fetching all the 'place' values in database and i am getting outofbox exception.
Any piece of code is highly appreciated.
[image]

Query returned all the fields instead of a specific one, here is when i tried it with onlinesqlite[image]
This specific latitude & logitude value only falls inside of any one of the rows in database

The correct answer from mysql is:-[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481895

Comment: Did you notice that that's not the same query you have in your code? `AND` is different than `&`.

Comment: @ Mike M, Yes Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings should be between two `""` so the definition of your strings is not correct, maybe you mean double.
To solve your problem you need to cast your string to a number using `CAST('number' as DOUBLE)` and you have to use `AND` instead of `&` like you already mention in comment for example :

```
double lat = 10.017860;
double lon = 76.342782;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select place from mytable where " 
        + lat + " >= CAST(sw_lat as DOUBLE) AND " 
        + lat + " <= CAST(ne_lat as DOUBLE) AND " 
        + lon + " >= CAST(sw_lon as DOUBLE) AND " 
        + lon + " <= CAST(ne_lon as DOUBLE)", null);
```

**Note** you don't need to use lat and lon between `''`

[read this](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr)

Take a look for this [demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-593bbf6e666e7l1kj3r3gd9h) :

[image: demo]

Comment: Then do I have to change the lat & lon to decimal?

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: does sqlite support comparing double with decimal?

Comment: I'm sorry it failed. still returning all the place and getting "Cursor index outofbox exception"

Comment: i have a screenshot, how to share it with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146318/discussion-between-jasim-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @jasim read the link of Mike M. this **"Cursor index outofbox exception"** is another problem you can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481895/android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-1-requested

Comment: it happened because the query returned many results while my query is supposed to returns only two values and it works in mysql.

Comment: i have tried your sugession in the SQLite online and it also failed, please have a look. https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-593bbf6e666e7l1kj3r3gd9h

Comment: what did you mean it fail @jasim did you click to the run button?

Comment: @jasim can you share the link of this database?

Comment: I tried in the previous comment but when I clicked , it is not showing my database. I can drop it in your inbox, if you like

Comment: no, you have to save it using **Fiddle** button in top it will gives you a link you can share it @jasim

Comment: ok, thanks. i got it for you.Hope you can help me now https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-593bcbe8666e8l1kj3r5ctrf

Comment: @jasim what result you expect to get?

Comment: i figured out the problem, i should use 'and' instead of '&'. Thank you very much for your concern, if you correct your answer, ill give you tick.